# Excel 2016 "SQL-like" Join Data from Different Worksheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two worksheets in one Excel file that I would like to do a "sql-like" join and select on.

Sheet1 has an ID column (among other columns)
Sheet2 has an ID column and a corresponding column with either the text "Yes" or "No"

I'd like to add a new column to Sheet1 that displays the "Yes"/"No" text value from Sheet2 for the id of the row in Sheet1.

I imagine the pseudo-code for the new column in Sheet1 would be something like:

```
=Select Sheet2.YesNo From Sheet2 Join Sheet1 On Sheet1.id = Sheet2.id
```

*I can't just sort both and paste because Sheet1 does not have all of the exact same IDs.

Comment: Use [power pivot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg413497(v=sql.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, a simple VLOOKUP will solve pull the Yes/No from Sheet2 with the correct ID from Sheet1. Input this code on cell B2 of Sheet1 - assuming `$A$1:$B$20` is the data range of Sheet2 with column A is the ID and column B is the Yes/No data.

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$20,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: THANK YOU! VLOOKUP worked. I had heard of it before, but wasn't quite sure how it worked. Your example was spot on.